I face the Java Problem MY program gave me error .UnsatisfiedLinkError but the file is they
I have a Java program that uses a native DLL file. It works perfectly on my development machine but fails with a UnsatisfiedLinkError or a "file not found" error when I run it on another device.
I already set all the settings for the dll and intelliJ and it still gave this error and I also checked dll and java is 64 bit.
The file is in the correct location.
My Questions:

What are other potential reasons the DLL cannot be found, even if it
exists at the specified path?
Are there any additional system or Java configurations required to load native libraries on a new device?
Could this be related to dependencies in the DLL itself, and if so,    how can I debug this?


#Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:
C:\Users\foru\CLionProjects\CheckerGameLibrary\cmake-build-debug\libCheckerGameLibrary.dll
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2422)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2025)
at main.Main.(Main.java:156)
Process finished with exit code 1#

    package main;
    
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    //i send you complete file just unzip that and i set the setting in the code so set the run into Current file like that
    public class Main {
        private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
        private long gamePtr; // Pointer to the C++ game instance
        private int[][] boardState; // 2D array to hold board state
        private JButton[][] buttons; // To keep track of buttons for painting
        private JLabel turnLabel; // Label to show which player's turn it is
        private int selectedRow = -1; // No piece selected initially
        private int selectedCol = -1; // No piece selected initially
    
        public Main() {
            // Initialize the game and fetch the initial board state
            gamePtr = nativeCreate();
            boardState = fetchBoardState();
    
            // Set up GUI
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checker Game");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 600); // Increased size for better visual
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // Use BorderLayout for the frame
    
            // Create the turn label
            turnLabel = new JLabel("Current Turn: Player " + getCurrentPlayer(gamePtr));
            turnLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame.add(turnLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Add label at the top
    
            JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE));
            buttons = new JButton[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    
            initializeBoard(boardPanel);
            frame.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Add board panel to the center
    
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public void initializeBoard(JPanel boardPanel) {
            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                    final int finalRow = row; // Declare final variable for row
                    final int finalCol = col; // Declare final variable for col
    
                    JButton button = new JButton() {
                        @Override
                        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                            drawPiece(g, finalRow, finalCol); // Use finalRow and finalCol
                        }
                    };
    
                    // Set button background color based on the position
                    if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                        button.setBackground(new Color(255, 206, 158)); // Light color
                    } else {
                        button.setBackground(new Color(186, 120, 49)); // Dark color
                    }
                    button.setOpaque(true);
                    button.setBorderPainted(false); // Remove button border
                    buttons[row][col] = button; // Store button reference
    
                    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (selectedRow == -1) { // No piece selected
                                if (boardState[finalRow][finalCol] == getCurrentPlayer(gamePtr)) {
                                    selectedRow = finalRow;
                                    selectedCol = finalCol;
                                    button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); // Highlight selected piece
                                }
                            } else { // Piece has been selected
                                if (movePiece(gamePtr, selectedRow, selectedCol, finalRow, finalCol)) {
                                    boardState = fetchBoardState(); // Refresh board state after move
                                    updateTurnLabel(); // Update turn label after a successful move
                                    checkGameOver(); // Check if game is over
                                }
                                resetSelection(); // Clear selection regardless of move success
                            }
                            updateBoard(); // Update the visual board
                        }
                    });
    
                    boardPanel.add(button); // Add button to the board panel
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void drawPiece(Graphics g, int row, int col) {
            if (boardState != null && boardState[row][col] != 0) {
                int pieceColor = boardState[row][col];
                g.setColor(pieceColor == 1 ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                g.fillOval(10, 10, 50, 50); // Adjusted size of pieces
            }
        }
    
        public int[][] fetchBoardState() {
            int[] array = getBoardState(gamePtr); // Replace jintArray with int[]
            int[][] state = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    
            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                    state[row][col] = array[row * BOARD_SIZE + col]; // Adjust for 1D indexing
                }
            }
            return state;
        }
    
        public void updateBoard() {
            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                    buttons[row][col].repaint(); // Repaint each button
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void updateTurnLabel() {
            int currentPlayer = getCurrentPlayer(gamePtr); // Get the current player
            turnLabel.setText("Current Turn: Player " + currentPlayer); // Update label text
        }
    
        public void checkGameOver() {
            int winner = checkWinner(gamePtr);
            if (winner != 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player " + winner + " wins!");
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again?", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    resetGame();
                } else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void resetGame() {
            resetGameNative(gamePtr); // Reset the game on the native side
            boardState = fetchBoardState(); // Refresh the board state
            updateBoard(); // Repaint the board
            updateTurnLabel(); // Update the turn label for a fresh start
        }
    
        public void resetSelection() {
            if (selectedRow != -1 && selectedCol != -1) {
                buttons[selectedRow][selectedCol].setBackground((selectedRow + selectedCol) % 2 == 0 ? new Color(255, 206, 158) : new Color(186, 120, 49));
            }
            selectedRow = -1;
            selectedCol = -1;
        }
    
        static {
            //here in main function paste that
          //  System.out.println("Loading library from: " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));// donot change that because we both have same name just change
            System.load("C:/Users/foru/CLionProjects/CheckerGameLibrary/cmake-build-debug/libCheckerGameLibrary.dll");
            // Correct way to load
        }
        public native long nativeCreate();
        public native int[] getBoardState(long ptr); // Change jintArray to int[]
        public native boolean movePiece(long ptr, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol); // Native method to move pieces
        public native int getCurrentPlayer(long ptr); // Get the current player's ID
        public native int checkWinner(long ptr); // Native method to check for winner
        public native void resetGameNative(long ptr); // Native method to reset the game
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
        }
    }


Is the DLL located in the location (path and directory) stated in the exception message? Do all parts of the path exist?

Did you set a PATH variable to specify where all DLLs are found?

Why the C++ tag?

Quote format is not good for errors. Use [code block] format instead.

What is the actual name of the DLL in the directory? [edit] the question to add a directory listing from the command line.

Hi Hannan Sani, welcome, sorry, but I am going to ask a very silly question, have you changed the absolute path of your machine, to suit the new machine?

If you add System.out.println(Files.isReadable(Path.of("C:/Users/foru/CLionProjects/CheckerGameLibrary/cmake-build-debug/libCheckerGameLibrary.dll"))); to your static block, what does it print?

Throw the dll into dependencies.exe or dependency walker. Normally you get some detailed indication why the library failed to load.

It probably isn't C:\Users\foru\CLionProjects\CheckerGameLibrary\cmake-build-debug\libCheckerGameLibrary.dll that isn't there - it is probably something that DLL needs to load (like the debug MSVC runtime DLL - it has a different name than the non-debug MSVC runtime DLL.)
